# How to connect table User, Offers and Car with relation mysql Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have three table which i must connect. Users, Car, Offer. Every car can have much offers. User can have much cars(that is connect). My task now is connect Car with their offers and user but i am bit confused now. Look my migration and models. Question is simple how to connect Car with Offers and Users. One user can send one offer.

cars migrations:

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('car_type');
    $table->string('mark');
    $table->longText('car_accessories');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
```

offers migrations:

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('car_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
```

Car model:

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

User model:

```
public function cars(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Car', 'user_id');
}
```

Offer model:

```
?
```

Answer (score 3):

As you say : 

**1** *User* to **Many** *Cars* 
**1** *User* to **1** *Offer* 
**1** *Car*  to **Many** *Offers*

So, here are 3 relationships, and for each you have to declare `the inverse` as well. So, totally here must be 6 relationship functions in Models.

User model:

```
public function cars(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Car', 'user_id');
}

public function offer(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Offer');
}
```

Car model :

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

public function offers() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Offer');
    }
```

Offer model :

```
public function car() {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One user can send one offer per car?

In your Offer model you will have:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function car() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
}
```

Then in your car model you can add the Offer relationship:

```
public function offer() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Offer::class);
}
```

And to retrieve the offer for each car that the user has done you can do it like this:

```
User::find(1)->with('cars.offer')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Offer and Car Models relations,it depends on how you want to connect them, here is the solutions I am thinking of:

1. User has one Offer and Car has one Offer, and this Offer belongs to one User and one Car.
   offers_table (id, price, user_id, car_id)
   cars_table (id, car_type, mark, car_accessories)

User Model

```
 public function offer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Offer');
}
```

Offer Model

```
 public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Car Model

```
 public function offer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Offer');
}
```

2. User has one Offer and Car hasMany Offers, and this Offer belongs to one User and one Car.
offers_table (id, price, user_id, car_id)
cars_table(id, car_type, mark, car_accessories)

User Model

```
 public function offer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Offer');
}
```

Offer Model

```
 public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Car Model

```
 public function offer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

3. User has one Offer and Car hasMany Offers, and each Offer belongs to one User and many Cars.
   offers_table (id, price, user_id)
   cars_table(id, car_type, mark, car_accessories)
   pivot table [cars_offers] (id, offer_id, car_id)

User Model

```
 public function offer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Offer');
}
```

Offer Model

```
public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Car Model

```
 public function offer()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer');
}
```